# Serve content from server to remote embed HTML

Tags: web-services, html, websockets

The title is very bad so let me explain what I need to know. I have a server with let's say different images. What I want to achieve is be able to embed a frame, into any HTML site, and be the server the one that determines what image to show on that remote frame.

Imagine the situation where you want to add a piece of advertising to your site, but you just need to paste a piece of JS or HTML into your HTML and be the advertising seller be in charge of showing whatever he wants on the size of the frame.

My question is what is this technique/technology named ? What should I know, is it websockets ?, is it embedding ? How could I achieve this ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to achieve it is to use `<iframe>` element in HTML which is use to embed another document inline of the current HTML document.

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_iframe.asp

Otherway to do it, would be to use JavaScript. You would have a JavaScript file which adds dynamic elements to the site. You could host it on your server and ask websites to include it via Link.